# How to prevent word-wrap in an IE Content Editable div?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, contenteditable

**The Problem**

I have a `div` that has `contenteditable` set to `true`.  In Chrome, when the edge of the `div` is reached while typing, it shifts the entire word to the next line as expected.  I present Exhibit A:

[image]

IE, as usual, doesn't behave as expected.  When the edge of the `div` is reached while typing it breaks the word.  I present Exhibit B:

[image]

**The HTML**

A simple `div`, with the `contenteditable` set to true:

```
<div id='bioEntryContainer' contenteditable='true' class='form-control'></div>
```

**The CSS**

The `form-control` is from Twitter's Bootstrap CSS.  The custom styles are:

```
#bioEntryContainer { min-height:74px; overflow:auto; }
```

**Attempts to Fix**

I've tried the following with CSS, with no luck:

```
overflow:hidden;
overflow-x:hidden;
white-space:nowrap;
white-space:pre;
display:inline-block;
```

I've tried the route suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716836/ie7-contenteditable-word-wrapping), but it didn't work.  Any other suggestions?

**Update**

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/4Ye6z/) to demo the problem, but I can't recreate it there.  I've included the Bootstrap CSS to get it as close to the actual environment as possible.

The `div` is added in the Bootstrap Modal with JS.  I'm not sure how that could change things, but hopefully that provides more background information.

Comment: Exhibits? You fancy now!

Comment: try this css: `white-space:pre-line;`

Comment: @fnostro No effect with the `white-space:pre-line`, sorry!

Answer (score 3):

Which IE versions have you tried so far?

I've tried it in IE 9-11 and no such problem persists.

Try setting

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

in your css style.

Comment: +1 because this got me in the right direction, finally.  There were other styles getting in the way.